# Flutter: The app crashes while using FFI (C++) plugin. I can't control it with debug tool becuase it stops responding

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

The application crashes when using the FFI (C++) plugin. I can't control this with the debug tool because it stops responding the moment the function from the c++ library is run. It tries to convert 180 mb ori file to 10mb jpg file.

Problem: during the conversion of a panoramic image (360 degrees) from ori to jpg format, the application crashes. From observations, this happens in different ways, sometimes after the 1st launch, sometimes after the 5th, I did almost all the tests on android, and then I wanted to switch to iOS.

Conversion on android takes about 65-70 seconds, on iOS about 12 seconds. When I call in a separate iOS isolate, it immediately crashes with the error exc_resource resource_type_memory (LIMIT 2098 MB, UNSUED=0X0)

Documentation and sdk: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1-OXae23cmymYcWUld7OMNlfUyIfr2kVk

Code: https://github.com/murat-ti/xphasepro/

Test ori file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KVSINq4jLDbFA-odFzL6VsOzXnAWvvj9/view?usp=sharing

Jpg file conversion result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJwaMCIdDzkCiOWKcx1hy26W2BWa6a8i/view?usp=sharing

You need to run the example project and click Get List -> Start stitch, which just does the conversion, now it will not work because you will need to throw the test ori file into the cache directory for the conversion to work.

More details: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/131590